# Use of a For/While loop inside another For/While loop for dual integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, procedural-programming, iterators

Can anyone please give suggestion for using For/While loop inside For/While loop for integrating a function with respect to two variables say for-

$\qquad r = (x^2 + (a/y^2))^(-1/2)$

Integration is with respect to $x$ and $y$ with limits 0 to 1 for both, $a$ is any arbitrary constant.

Comment: `Integrate[(x^2 + (a/y^2))^(-1/2), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]`

Comment: `Integrate[(x^2 + (a/y^2))^(-1/2), {y, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}]` take longer time.

Comment: If you really really want to use nested `For` then study `volume=0;For[x=0,x<1,x+=1/10, For[y=0,y<1,y+=1/10,volume=volume+1/10*1/10*((x+1/20)^2 + (a/(y+1/20)^2))^(-1/2)]]` and look at the value of `volume` when this is done. Study that. Think about what that is doing. Really try to understand the thinking behind that.

Comment: Thank you Bill. I will definitely try it.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @cvgmt (assuming here that `a>0`)

```
res=Integrate[(x^2 + (a/y^2))^(-1/2), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> a > 0]
```

[image]

And a quick check:

```
NIntegrate[(x^2 + (a/y^2))^(-1/2) /. a -> 2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

0.3406417035798416`

```
res/. a-> 2.
```

0.3406417035798416`